# Can I do array destructuring in VimL?

Tags: vimscript, variables

Can I do this in Vimscript?

```
let [a, b] = s:MyFunc()

function! s:MyFunc()
  return [1, 2]
endfunction
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can, but Vim calls it *list unpacking*.  It can be found in Vim's help:

```
:h let-unpack
```

Vim allows you to create and populate two variables from a list:

```
let [var1, var2] = mylist
```

which is equivalent to:

```
let var1 = mylist[0]
let var2 = mylist[1]
```

There is also an (untagged) section on that help page titled "List unpack".  It says you can do:

```
let [var1, var2; rest] = mylist
```

to collect an optional unknown number of items in a list.

And you can use a related trick to perform operations on multiple existing variables at once:

```
let [var1, var2] += 1
```

There is lots to like about this language.

However I don't believe any such magic is available for Dictionaries as of yet.

Comment: Who's "you" ? `let [personality1, personality2] = MeAsksMeAlsoAnswers()` :)